# How do I push to an embedded array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongoose

I'd like stores (grocery stores, restaurants, gyms, etc) with different types of sections. They're unique to the object in the array. A gym is going to have different sections than a grocery store, for example.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  store: [
      {
        name: String,
        section: Array,
      }
  ],
});
```

I got this working with simply store: Array (in the UserSchema), but I changed store to an object inside the array. How do I push to objects within store?

```
$scope.storeUpdate = function(){
        Users.get({email:$scope.global.user.email}, function(user3) {
            // Changing store.push to store.name.push gives the error: user3 not defined
            // If in UserSchema the store: type: Array, then user3[0].store.push works fine
            user3[0].store.section.push($scope.datStore.name);
            user3[0].$update(function(response) {
                // This just updates user changes on the webpage
                Users.query({}, function(users) {
                    $scope.users = users;
                    $scope.global.user = response;
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

Edit: Should I just embed a second schema?

Comment: can only push to an array, like `user3[0].store.section.push...` Would help if you expanded further detail on your goals

Comment: It's saying 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' when I do user3[0].store.section.push

Comment: not clear what ` I changed store to an object` means. It is an array in code shown which conflicts with statement

Comment: Store has an object within an array. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user3[0].store.name.push($scope.datStore.name);
```

you're pushing into store.name which is a string object (not an array)

you can change your schema if you want to push into store.name

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  store: [
      {
        name: Array,
        section: Array,
      }
  ],
});
```

Then you'll be able to push into user3[0].store.name

**EDIT**

you have Schema as there's an object having property store, where store is an array containing objects, and those objects will have properties name and section.. So just push objects into store.

Just decide what the schema should be, your aim is to push data into store right?

so you have to build up the object before pushing. for example

```
var obj ={ 
   name: $scope.datStore.name, 
   section: ["grocery","utensils"]
}
```

then just push your object into the store array.

```
user3[0].store.push(obj);
```

In short, create the object to be pushed into store before pushing it into store array

you can push data to the section like this (before pushing the object into store

```
var obj ={ 
    name: $scope.datStore.name, 
    section: []
}

obj.section.push(someSource1.section); //grocery
obj.section.push(someSource2.section); //utensils
```

then push into store

```
user3[0].store.push(obj); // here object being pushed will be {name:"",section:["grocery","utensils"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed my name to Array and it's saying "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined." If I change store to store[0], it says "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined."

Comment: I changed the question to say section instead of name.

Comment: Can you show the data (json) which you're getting as user3 in your function?

Comment: Thank you so much! Building the object first fixed it!!

Comment: I'll try to remember to upvote this when I get 15 reputation. I accepted it as an answer, so hopefully you get points!

Comment: It looks like everything works fine, but the store isn't permanently saved. As soon as I refresh the page the store disappears and it says store: Array[0].

Comment: You are getting data from server, then you are pushing your object into the store object.. But are you posting it back to the server? You need to use $http.post function to post back to server

That will save the data permanently. Otherwise you're just playing with client side variables